# Is it possible to create a function only for a catch block?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-remoting

I have multiple `try catch` blocks and all of them are using the same `catch` block.

```
    try {   
        invoke-command -cn $host -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
        param($name)    
        statement...
        } -ArgumentList $name
        
    } catch {
        $formatstring = "{0} : {1}`n{2}`n" +
                    "    + CategoryInfo          : {3}`n" +
                    "    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : {4}`n"
        write-host ($formatstring)
        exit 1
    }

...

    try {   
    another statement...
        
    } catch {
        $formatstring = "{0} : {1}`n{2}`n" +
                    "    + CategoryInfo          : {3}`n" +
                    "    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : {4}`n"
        write-host ($formatstring)
        exit 1
    }
```

I want to ask if it is possible to create a function which has the `catch` block so that I can call and use the function instead of writing the same `catch block` multiple times.

I am using `poweshell 5`

Comment: Seems like you're just trying to replicate the `$Error` default formatting output in which case why not just use `$_` in your catch block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) requires a *literal* `{ ... }` block to follow it, but from *inside* that block you're free to call reusable code, such as a function, or, in the simplest case, a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks):

```
# Define a script block to use in multiple `catch` blocks.
$sb = {
  "[$_]" # echo the error message
}

# Two simple sample try / catch statements:

try {
  1 / 0
}
catch {
  . $sb # `. <script-block>` invokes the block directly in the current scope
}

try {
  Get-Item -NoSuchParam
}
catch {
  . $sb
}
```

Note: `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-), is used to invoke the script block *directly in the current scope*, allowing you to directly modify that scope's variables.  This makes the script block behave as if it were used directly as the `catch` black.

If, by contrast, you want to execute the script block in a *child [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes)*, use `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a *ScriptBlock* which can be called using the [Invocation (*call* - &) Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#call-operator-).

```
$callMe = {
    $formatstring = "{0} : {1}`n{2}`n" +
    "    + CategoryInfo          : {3}`n" +
    "    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : {4}`n"
    Write-Host -Object $formatstring
    exit 1
}

try {   
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $host -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
        param($name)    
            # statement...
    } -ArgumentList $name -ErrorAction "Stop"
} 
catch {
    & $callMe
}
```

As a side note, if you ever find yourself repeating code, there is probably something you can do about that. I would suggest either setting [$ErrorActionPreference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2) to stop, or add a `-ErrorAction "Stop"` to your `Invoke-Command` to ensure a terminating error is thrown.

- *Best practice is to set `$ErrorActionPreference` back to `"Continue"` if used.*
- I also believe you're looking to use the `-f` (*format*) operator.